# What does the gdb 'x' command do?

Tags: memory, assembly, gdb, cpu-registers

In my quest to learn more about the computer in general, I stumbled upon a book which has some chapters about disassembling, the x86 assembly language, and the relationship between C and x86 assembly. Now I have been reading this `GDB` command but I am unable to fully understand it.

The command, along with its results, follows:

```
(gdb) x/32xw $esp
0xbffff7e0:    0xb8000ce0 0x08048510 0xbffff848 0xb7eafebc
0xbffff7f0:    0x00000002 0xbffff874 0xbffff880 0xb8001898
0xbffff800:    0x00000000 0x00000001 0x00000001 0x00000000
0xbffff810:    0xb7fd6ff4 0xb8000ce0 0x00000000 0xbffff848
0xbffff820:    0x40f5f7f0 0x48e0fe81 0x00000000 0x00000000
0xbffff830:    0x00000000 0xb7ff9300 0xb7eafded 0xb8000ff4
0xbffff840:    0x00000002 0x08048350 0x00000000 0x08048371
0xbffff850:    0x08048474 0x00000002 0xbffff874 0x08048510
```

Now, from what I understand, the command that I issue tells the debugger to:

- x (first one): examine the memory
- 32: get 32 of what follows
- x: enable hexadecimal representation
- w: show me `Word` size data.
- `**Note:**` I know that I ask about the esp register, but I don't quite fully understand what $ is doing in front of it. When I try not to use it, I get a missing symbol error, so I get it has something to do with reference/de-reference?

What has been bugging me is how did I find all those bytes? Since I am examining a register, who's size is 32 bit, shouldn't I get only 32 bits, or 4 bytes (only 1 row of the above)? If I am correct with my assumption, then were did we find the rest of the data? Does it have to do something with the stack, and a particular stack frame, which I currently am unaware of?

I would appreciate your input so that I can clarify things in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's giving you 32 words of memory where the `esp` register is pointing (apparently that register contains the address 0xbffff7e0).

Answer (score 4):

```
(gdb) help x   
Examine memory: x/FMT ADDRESS.
```

Giving $esp as the address will make gdb fetch whatever is in that register and use that as the memory address for the x command - and will show you the following 32 words in memory starting at that address.

variables within gdb itself are names prefixed with a $ , gdb sets up predefined variables for all the cpu registers.

If you want to inspect the esp register, use  the command `info registers esp`, as you'll see with your example (x/32xw $esp), the esp register contains the first address shown, 0xbffff7e0

Answer (score 1):

(gdb) x/32xw $esp
it means show me the 32 words field where esp points.

pieces:32,
format:hex ,
size:word (1 word= 32 bit on gdb)

show me the 32 words field where esp points
(hex)0xbffff7e0 - (hex)0xbffff7f0 =   (dec)3221223392 - (dec)3221223408 = 16bytes=4words

Comment: Note that GDB "word" size is doesn't necessarily match the ISA's definition of a "word".  e.g. on x86 (including x86-64), the documentation uses word = 16-bit, like `movzx eax, word ptr [rdi]` or `cwd`.