# How to switch gdb byte output grouping

Tags: linux, debugging, assembly, memory, gdb

When I try to see what's inside stack space, I use the following command:

```
x/100x $sp
```

However, sometimes output is formatted like this, grouping by 4 bytes:

```
0xbffff0ac: 0x00000000  0xb7fbc000  0xb7fbc000  0xbffff4e8
...
```

While sometimes I get this:

```
0xbffff0ac: 00 00 00 00 00 c0 fb b7 00 c0 fb b7 e8 f4 ff bf
```

But I can't determine how to switch between these formats and how gdb desides which format to use for output. Any suggestions?

Comment: `x/100b <address>` provides bytes, `x/100s <address>` provides shorts, etc. Also see questions like [What does the gdb 'x' command do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11890253/608639), [Formatting on gdb examine memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31442407/608639) and [GDB examine data display format from 8 bytes in a row to 4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21060184/608639).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> sometimes output is formatted like this
>   However, sometimes output is formatted like this

This is because the `x` command remembers the last size you used.

If you want particular size with your `x`, just specify it directly:

```
(gdb) x/100wx $sp
```

[Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html).